# How to organize sharing with friends in the Android application

Tags: android, callback, social-networking, playmaker

I'm writing an application for android and it has a feature that will share with friends on social networks. When someone passes by the link and downloads the application from the play market, after installing the application, the person who posted the link, receives bonuses for installation by other people. Tell me in which direction I need to read or how such a callback is organized

Comment: Look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/